# mySQL how to group the months by years

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am doing a mobile app for consult the database
I have a table like this
[image: table]
I want to do a collapsible list from `date_creation` by year->month->day, like this
[image: collapsible list]
To do that, I need to put the loops in the nested collapsible blocks,
First I did this query for the years

```
$count_year = $bdd -> query
(
    'SELECT YEAR(date_creation) as y, COUNT(id) as nombre
     FROM rdv
     GROUP BY y
     ORDER BY y DESC'
);
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h3>sort by date</h3>
    <?php foreach ($count_year as $key) { ?>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h1><?php echo $key['y']; ?></h1>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

which give me the years
[image: years]
then I tried this to get the months group by year

```
$count_month = $bdd -> query
(
    'SELECT YEAR(date_creation) as y, MONTH(date_creation) as m, COUNT(id) as nombre
     FROM rdv
     WHERE YEAR(date_creation) = YEAR(date_creation)
     GROUP BY y, m
     ORDER BY y DESC, m DESC'
);
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h3>sort by date</h3>
    <?php foreach ($count_year as $key) { ?>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h1><?php echo $key['y']; ?></h1>
        <?php foreach ($count_month as $key) { ?>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h1><?php echo $key['m']; ?></h1>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

In phpmyAdmin I get the result like this
[image: months]
which group the months by year, but the result in Chrome, it put all the months in one year, like this
[image: months wrong]
I know I need to group the months in mySQL by `WHERE YEAR(date_creation) =` **something present year dynamically**, or maybe is just the html is wrong, cause the jQuery mobile CDN will create lots tags in DOM.
Any idea how to put the 12 to 2016?
And so on for the days group by month.

Comment: I think your app can do all the counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two queries. Just use one query and start a new year DIV whenever the year changes.

```
$count_month = $bdd -> query
(
    'SELECT YEAR(date_creation) as y, MONTH(date_creation) as m, COUNT(id) as nombre
     FROM rdv
     WHERE YEAR(date_creation) = YEAR(date_creation)
     GROUP BY y, m
     ORDER BY y DESC, m DESC'
);
$last_year = 0;
?>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h3>sort by date</h3>
    <?php 
    foreach ($count_month as $key) { 
        if ($key['y'] != $last_year) {
            if ($last_year) { // Close DIV for previous year if this is set ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            } ?>
            <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h1><?php echo $key['y']; ?></h1>
            <?php
            $last_year = $key['y'];
        }
        ?>
        <div data-role="collapsible">
            <h1><?php echo $key['m']; ?></h1>
            <div><?php echo $key['nombre']; ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Here's the version that adds days within months:

```
<?php
$count_month = $bdd -> query
(
    'SELECT YEAR(date_creation) as y, MONTH(date_creation) as m, DAY(date_creation) AS d, COUNT(id) as nombre
     FROM rdv
     WHERE YEAR(date_creation) = YEAR(date_creation)
     GROUP BY y, m, d
     ORDER BY y DESC, m DESC, d DESC'
);

?>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <h3>sort by date</h3>
    <?php 
    $last_year = 0;
    foreach ($count_month as $key) { 
        if ($key['y'] != $last_year) {
            if ($last_year) { // Close DIV for previous year and month if this is set
                ?>
                </div> <!-- end month <?php echo $last_month; ?> -->
                </div> <!-- end year <?php echo $last_year; ?> -->
                <?php
            } ?>
            <div data-role="collapsible"> <!-- start year -->
            <h1><?php echo $key['y']; ?></h1>
            <?php
            $last_year = $key['y'];
            $last_month = 0;
        }
        if ($key['m'] != $last_month) {
            if ($last_month) { // Close DIV for previous month
                ?>
                </div> <!-- end month <?php echo $last_month; ?> -->
                <?php
            }
            $last_month = $key['m'];
            ?>
            <div data-role="collapsible"> <!-- start month -->
            <h2><?php echo $key['m']; ?></h2>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div data-role="collapsible"> <!-- date -->
        <h3><?php echo $key['d']; ?></h3>
        <div><?php echo $key['nombre']; ?></div>
        </div> <!-- end date -->
        <?php }
    if ($last_month) { ?>

        </div> <!-- end month <?php echo $last_month; ?> -->
               <?php
               }
    if ($last_year) { ?>
        </div> <!-- end year <?php echo $last_year; ?> -->
               <?php }
    ?>
</div> <!-- end main -->
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/YfD9pL)

Comment: I tried your code, it works, BUT I don't understand why? Base on your code, the first loop, it compares if the year "2017" is not egale 0, and then if 0 return true, it creats an `</div>` to end the first `<div>` which has no collapase "year" inside, in this case, `$last_year = 0`, it returns always `true`, how can the code go out of this if condiction? Cause if I don't understand your code, I can't do the same thing to group the days by month.

Comment: The second `if` if to close the `<div>` for the previous year. But if `$last_year == 0` then there is no previous year.

Comment: I still don't get it, I understand the rest except two `if`,  when the loop goes first time in the 1st `if`, `$key['y'] = 2017`, `$last_year = 0`,  it returns true, so it goes to 2nd `if`, which `$last_year = 0` returns always true, so it creates an `</div>`, I know out of the 2nd `if` you change `$last_year = 2017`, once it becomes 2016, then it will trigger the two `if`, but since the first time of the loop, `2017 != 0`,  why can it sitll go out of the first `if`, write the html and change the value of `$last_year`? And if it creates a `</div>`, who is it's beggin tag?

Comment: I tried to do the same thing to group the days by month, but as I don't understand how it works your code, I can't do that, even at last, I need to get the rows group by days, I don't know how to nest your code from layer to layer, cause there are too many `</div>` lost their beginning `<div>`, some help please

Comment: When the year changes you set `$last_month = 0;`. And whenever `$key['m'] != $last_month` you start another DIV for the month.

Comment: any chance you can write this code to show me please, because in my code, all the <div> are mess up, I don't know where to place the end `}` for the new `if`, in my html, I can't find the match bigging and ending <div> cause the first `<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">` match the </div> in the 2nd if, and it makes the last `</div>` to be an orphan tag, and the result in chrome is a mess too

Comment: Thanks! I'll study this update right now, and I'll tell you as soon as it' done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143718/discussion-between-jiang-lan-and-barmar).